# How do I identify which apps utilize an expiring certificate

Tags: connected-apps

I have a cert expiring soon. Do I have to go through all connected apps to find out which app is using this cert.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does appear to be the case that you'll need to trawl through them one at a time. Connected Apps don't really use certificates stored in Salesforce's `Certificate and Key Management` though.

If your connected app is using digital signatures (which I've only encountered when setting up a connected app to be able to use the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer flow), that certificate can't simply be a reference to a cert stored in Salesforce (not in the way that using the `Auth.JWS` class or a Named Credential can, at least)

The first thing I'd think of when trying to get programmatic access to metadata is to see if you can write a SOQL query. The SOAP API is a good resource for that, even if you're not using SOAP, and [there is a page on ConnectedApplication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_connectedapplication.htm). That object does appear to be queryable (you might need to click the "use tooling API" checkbox if going through the developer console), but the information about which certificate it is configured to use does not appear to be exposed.

This is a good time to document which connected apps use which certificates, so that you don't need to repeat this work again.

Comment: thank you @Derek for your clarification and help.

Comment: @Aleem In case you aren't aware, if there is an answer that solves your problem (or answers the question, in this case) you are encouraged to upvote and/or accept an answer. Upvoting and accepting is completely optional (though leaving questions unaccepted may deter some people from spending time on furutre questions you may ask). Doing so helps signal to other people with similar questions that the accepted answer is likely to work/be correct, signals to other contributors that the question doesn't need any more attention, and gives both you and the answerer "reputation" points.